# Twitter4J getUserTimeline returning incorrect values

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm having issues with the number of tweets I get back when using getUserTimeline.

This happens regardless of whether I use paging to get back more tweets or stick with the default of 20.
For example, I tested on the user "ionlyretweetok" and got back 18 tweets. On some users, I get back the correct value (18).

I read on the API "...retweets are stripped out of the user_timeline when calling in XML or JSON..." but the above user's tweets are only ever retweets.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it's an issue with the API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add the function call you're using in your code?

Comment: @Matt `twitter.getUserTimeline("username")`